# Checking if data exists on Firebase before creating User

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I have a little user login form, where the new user has to add his username, password and a nickname (as basic firebase auth only accepts e-mail as the username, right?).

This is a users structure I created on Firebase to receive the nickname [image]

The key is based on the username and it has 2 children: the nickname and username.

Before I try to create the user using the auth methods from Firebase, I query to check if the nickname already exists. If yes, it doesn't create the user and throws an alert. If nickname doesn't exists, it creates the user and then adds the nickname to the users structure from the image above.

Some time thinking and changing the code here and there (code was jumping the 'observeSingleEventOfType' and executing the createUser, before check for if the nickname already existed), I thought a good idea was to get the createUser code and add it directly inside the observeSingleEventOfType on the nickname query, as an 'else' for 'if snapshot.exists()'...

It appears to be working, but I don't know if it is the 'correct' way to perform it...

Is there another way (a better way) to do it?

The method is below.
Thanks!

```
 func createUser(username: String, password: String, nickname: String){

    var userCreated = false
    var errorCode = 0

    users.queryOrderedByChild("Nickname").queryEqualToValue(nickname).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            errorCode = 3
            self.delegate?.didReceiveResponseFromFirebaseCreateUser!(userCreated, errorCode: errorCode)
        }
        else{
            self.ref.createUser(username, password: password, withCompletionBlock: { (error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print (error.description)

                    if error.description.rangeOfString("EMAIL_TAKEN") != nil {
                        errorCode = 1
                    }
                    else if error.description.rangeOfString("INVALID_EMAIL") != nil {
                        errorCode = 2
                    }

                }
                else{
                    userCreated = true
                    let newUser = User(username: username, nickname: nickname)

                    let newUserRef = self.users.childByAppendingPath(username.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "-"))
                    newUserRef.setValue(newUser.toAnyObject())

                }

                self.delegate?.didReceiveResponseFromFirebaseCreateUser!(userCreated, errorCode: errorCode)

            })
        }


    })
}
```

Comment: Not needed for this question anymore, but in general: keep in mind that the picture of the JSON tree in your question is not nearly as useful as having the JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem when I was building my last Firebase app. The method I used to solve it was to create an additional mapping from username to user ids. So my structure looks something like that (uid is user id from Firebase auth):

```
users: {
   accounts: {
      uid1: { 
          username: frank,
          ...
      },
      uid2: { 
          username: monique,
          ...
      }
      ...
   },
   username_to_uid: {
      frank: uid1,
      monique: uid2,
      ...
   }
}
```

This allows two major things:

1. While user tries to register, you can check first if the username he provides already exists using "username_to_uid" mapping
2. You can also log in users using their usernames and password. By default, you can log in user using Firebase auth with an email and a password. Here, the idea is that for a given username you can easily retrieve uid associated with this username using "username_to_uid" mapping, so you can log in users with usernames and password.

Comment: Wow! Thats a great idea! I'll try it here. I'll surely give it a try.

Thank you!

Comment: @LucasAlmeida Great to hear that!

Comment: It will surely come in handy to make the auth process better (using the nickname instead of the email) but for the firebase-swift issue I'll need to figure out if I'll keep it the current way or not... 

As the observeSingleEventOfType behave asynchronously, before its block get executed it was executing the createUser, and the variable which returns true for an existent nickname was being sent as false, so multiple users were being created with the same nickname. Thats why I 'sandwiched' the createUser code inside the block of observeSingleEventOfType...

Comment: I'll keep searching for other options (although its working)... But I'll certainly use your idea for my login method!

Thank you again!

Comment: Great solution @pkacprzak. Don't forget to secure the data with security rule, so that no one can overwrite someone else's nickname (and only the owning uid can delete it).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen indeed. For now we don't handle deletions, but having security rule for write access is very important here. Actually, we use Firebase-Bold write our security rules and there we can use a very handy create rule which is perfect in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up on the synchronicity issue I had with the Firebase Event Observer:

Yesterday, I thought it was working, I had issues when calling a segue to open another viewController (it was calling the new view while the Observer was still running with no results and the application crashed because the delegate method was using wasn't declared on the other view)...

As as solution, I got rid of all delegates and recoded the methods using completion handlers... Now its going really fine!

Oh, and @pkacprzak: I made the changes and started using this 'bridge structure' to store the relation between nickname and uid. Man, now its kicking! Thank u very much for it!

Comment: Awesome! Speaking of completion handlers, there are such a great concept in chaining async tasks if one knows their power :) and it's great you're using them